# Fetching the complete results in sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I get the entire query executed in sqldeveloper, which would give me the time taken for execution?

As of now, it just fetches 50-100 rows, and fetches the rest as and when I scrolled down.

It must be a fairly simple solution, but googling it didn't help me. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click in your result grid and press `Ctrl-End`.

Comment: Be sure to subtract the time it takes to click and control end

Answer (score 1):

You will get every thing discussed here : https://community.oracle.com/thread/449344

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure query run-time metrics, i.e. not the time to fetch the rows to you client/sqldeveloper, you can use the following:

set timing on
set autotrace on
select * from ( {YOUR QUERY} ) where rownum = 0;